# Styling Google Maps - Javascript API v3 - Outline on coastlines?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to style up a Google Map to match a design I've been given, and on the design there is a stroke around the *outside* of all the countries, as well as a stroke on dividing borders.

The effect I'm going for is as below:
[image]

My code for the styling is currently as follows:

```
var styles =   [
        {
          featureType: "water",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "on" },
            { color: "#ffffff" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "landscape",
          stylers: [
            { color: "#f7f7f5" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "road",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "poi",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.country",
          stylers: [
            { color: "#d2cdcd" },
            { weight: 1 }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.country",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.province",
          elementType: "geometry",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.locality",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "administrative.province",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
          ]
        },{
          featureType: "water",
          elementType: "geometry.stroke",
          stylers: [
            { color: "#4cfff5" }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

Any idea if what I am after is possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT: The above styles give me the following**

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what those style settings give you?

Comment: I can indeed, see my updated question above.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll not be able to do this  with styled maps.

Comment: I concur with @Dr.Molle. There doesn't seem to be any way of getting coastlines outlined. Which is a pity.

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the comments though - I will give it back to design to rework :)

Answer (score 2):

You currently can only define the fill for water but not the outline.

Comment: How about now, 2018?

Comment: Six and a half years after [the issue was reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822845), nothing has changed.