# Coastlines in Google Maps

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to customize a map on Google Maps.
What I would like to do is to have a white map, with some borders and name. However, if I set it to white only, I do not get the coastlines (see picture below) and so it is impossible to distinguish land from sea.

Does someone know how to get the coastlines? Thanks a lot!

Here follows my code

```
[
    {
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#444444"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
       {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            },
            {
                "color":"#ffffff"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#a8a9a8"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#ffffff"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and the result is like that:

[image]

Comment: related question: [Styling Google Maps - Javascript API v3 - Outline on coastlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327019/styling-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-outline-on-coastlines)

Comment: Thanks. I see, I hope that in some years something has changed :)